# How to intersect polygon layer with my current GPS in android GIS sdk 100.2.1

Tags: java, android, gis

I am developing an application that has the feature layer in developers arcgis and I am having confusion how to get the intersection of the two data like my GPS and my polygon layer like I am entering in that current polygon layer like geofencing in android GIS.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon

Comment: i am using the arcgis rest server thanks for the formula anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference this is how i solve the problem in android gis:

```
  Geometry myGeom = GeometryEngine.buffer(featureLayer.getGeometry(),0);

  Point myLocation = locationDisplay.getMapLocation();

  boolean isIntersects = GeometryEngine.intersects(myGeom,myLocation);
```

Where myGeom is the geometry 2 parameters of geometry and distance and boolean intersects with parameter of 2 geometry but it also accepts points to check if the polygonLayer is intersecting with my current location.